# sharepoint2010 : javascript in Sharepoint 2010 using visual studio 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, validation

Can we use javascript in sharepoint 2010 web part using visual studio 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
See Creating a Web Part with Client-side Script

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584169(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: thanks madhur for the link. i have gone through it. i have another doubt that                                                        1. if we are using linked script file then what should be the location of that file?                                                             2. if i want to validate text box then how to pass text box value in javascript function?

Comment: You can put the script in layouts or embed it itself in dll

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize JavaScript in your web parts just as you would HTML or CSS.  As for it's location, a common place to store these files is in the Style Library.  You would then create a reference to the JavaScript file in your masterpage or page layout (depending on your needs) where it would be available at runtime.

I would recommend using SharePoint Designer for managing and versioning these style-related files.